# Vue computed property not updating on update of their reactive dependency

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, computed-properties, vue-reactivity

I am new to using get and set methods in Vue computed property. I have the following code in computed.

```
editSmallText: {
      get() {
        return this.word.translation.smallText.join("");
      },
      set(value) {
        if (typeof value == "string") this.editSmallTextArray = value.split("");
        else this.editSmallTextArray = value;
      },
    },
```

I am using this.editSmallText as v-model for input. And I have this.word as object in props of components and this.editSmallTextArray as array in the data. Now if I change something in input feild this.editSmallTextArray gets updated and I assign that updated value to this.word.translation.smallText inside a function and send this.word.translation.smallText's updated value to firebase's update function which update it in firebase firestore. And get the upated value in template as `{{ word.translation.smallText }}` but in my input v-model I still get the old value of this.word.translation.smallText in editSmallText v-model untill I refresh the page/reload component. I'm not sure why editSmallText is not getting updating on update of word.translation.smallText.

```
<p class="text-h5 q-mb-sm text-center" v-if="!editSmall">
              {{ word.translation.smallText.join("") }}
            </p>
            <q-input
              v-model="editSmallText"
              class="text-white"
              dense
              standout
              dark
              v-else
              autogrow
              sanitize
            />

<q-btn
              icon="edit"
              @click="editSmall = !editSmall"
              size="sm"
              round
              flat
              dense
              class="text-white"
              v-if="!editSmall"
            />

            
            <q-btn
              icon="save"
              class="text-white"
              @click="saveEditSmallText()"
              size="sm"
              v-if="editSmall"
              round
              flat
              dense
            />
```

`props: { word: Object, isSelected: Boolean },`

```
data(){
return {
      editSmall: false,
      editSmallTextArray: [],
      }
}
computed:{
editSmallText: {
      get() {
        return this.word.translation.smallText.join("");
      },
      set(value) {
        if (typeof value == "string")
          this.editSmallTextArray = value.split(",");
        else this.editSmallTextArray = value;
      },
    },
},
methods:{
saveEditSmallText() {
      this.editSmall = !this.editSmall;
      this.word.translation.smallText = this.editSmallTextArray;
      this.edit();
    },
edit() {
      let payload = {
        word: this.word.word,
        id: this.$el.id,
        updatedAt: new Date(),
        smallText: this.word.translation.smallText,
        dictionary: this.word.translation.orgTrans.dictionary,
        transcription: this.word.translation.orgTrans.transcription,
      };
      this.$store.dispatch("updateWord", payload);
      this.$q.notify({
        color: "positive",
        textColor: "white",
        icon: "update",
        position: "top",
        message: this.$t("Changes saved successfully!"),
        timeout: 3000,
      });
    },
}
```

Comment: You need to add more code ...or better yet, create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @MichalLevý kindly take a look now I have added more code including data and methods. See if it can help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's not updating is they are two separate object references.  Your v-model gets its value via the `get()` method from a prop, while updates are being saved to a `data` property in the `set()` method.

If you insist on using a prop to hold the value, your component should `$emit` any changes to that value in the `set()` method and let the parent component perform the actual update.

Alternatively you can clone the prop to your `data` when the component is `mounted()`, removing the need for a computed.  If the prop's value changes in the parent component, you will need to `watch` and update the `data` accordingly.

Comment: Thanks $emit() the changes to parent component resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

the word prop is reactive, but the translation property of the word prop is not reactive.

The translation property was most likely added afterwards

[image]

adding the translation property to word object does not trigger updated hook.

try to define a default value

```
props: {
  word: {
     type:Object,
     required: false,
     default: {
         translation: null
     }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was making a mistake by trying to update the `this.word.translation.smallText` inside the child component as it is a prop and should be updated via $emit in the actual component i.e parent component. My problem was solved once I updated the value of `this.word.translation.smallText` in its actual component from where I was getting it as a prop.